# Azure Cosmo DB Mocking In Integration Tests

Tags: azure, integration-testing, azure-cosmosdb

I have currently written Integration tests using Cosmos DB emulator. But I want to mock the response from Cosmos DB instead of emulator.

If integration tests use emulator the pipeline time increases. So looking for a way to mock the response what we get from emulator. Instead of using it directly in integration test. For example when call is made to the cosmos db then the response will be returned from a file.json which will have similar response as the db.

Please suggest any tool that can help here for mocking as using mock would be quicker than emulator.

Comment: Please edit your question to be specific - as written , it’s unclear what issue you are running into.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your question needs some work so the community can better help you. Take a look at [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and give it another try.